# cookieless domain to serve css and js - way to organize code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, static, cookieless

I would like to configure my environment to serve css and javascript files from static.example.com instead of example.com/static.

The second has the convenience that I can code my html pages to load the css and javascript files relatively eg "static/reset.css" independent of the actual domain.

Is there a good practice to avoid altering all my source files whenever I change

static.example.com to static.otherexample.com

as I would have to rewrite all my HTML source files importing css and javascript?

Comment: Use a CMS (Content Management System) and create a custom theme/template/view/structure.

Comment: A quick fix is to just configure your server that any requests to `static.example.com` are served from the current `static` directory.

Comment: @Michael: I would like to avoid sending useless cookies when retrieving static files. A quick fix but doesn't solve my requirement.

Comment: Sure it does. This is a different domain and cookies for `example.com` won't be sent. I've used this method before.

Comment: @MichaelMior Ah sure, from the browsers perspective it's a different domain and it will refuse to send cookies if set as absolute without inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some kind of configurable prefix to include js and css files. Depending on the technology you're using, it is helpful to have some kind of helper method for this. In ASP.NET MVC, I use some custom method like `CSS.Add("reset.css")`, which knows the path and URL.

The js files should not really care where they are loaded from. As for css, it's important to know that relative URLs in CSS are interpreted as relative to the URL the CSS was loaded from, *not* relative to the URL the page was loaded from. So make sure you understand that `background-image: url('/images/img1.png')` would also load from the static page (which is usually a good thing).

### The better way

It's best practice to compress, minify and merge all of the CSS / js files. Therefore, you should only have a very small number of files (one js, one css) to keep the number of requests low. The inclusion of these files would happen on the server, so the URLs don't matter. To implement this, you will need some kind of helper method (and a lot of compression logic, but there are libraries for all this).

For ASP.NET MVC there is [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher), but I'm sure there are plenty of tools for various environments.

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET well enough but basically you suggest a way of templating to replace (or extend in the case of CSS.Add("reset.css") ) a placeholder?

Comment: It's more than a placeholder - it will basically gather all files (on the server), parse them, minify and compress them, and create one file. This file is then served to the client. Using a different domain for serving that file is another improvement, but the minification/merge step is the more important one I believe.

Answer (score 0):

How is the html being generated?

You could use a config value or constant, and use that value for the domain portion of the url for any of the static assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a trick on the server, i.e. all your urls in HTML could be relative to `/static`, but once your server receive request, it can "change" the route and get files from `static.current-domain.com` instead of `current-domain.com/static`

Comment: nope, then the first request sent by the browser still sends cookies which the OP wants to avoid

Comment: @PaulPodlipensky I forgot to mention cookieless in my question but it is in the tags. Yes, avoiding unnecessary cookies is a goal.